# How to randomly generate a permutation P of the first n natural numbers that satisfies P[i] != i?

Tags: algorithm, random, combinations, permutation

I want to randomly generate a permutation `P` of the first n natural numbers, and it has to satisfy that `P[i] != i` for every `i<n`.

How can I do it efficiently?

---

The first method I came up with is just to randomly select legal numbers for each position iteratively. However I found it doesn't seem to guarantee the randomness.

For example in the case of 4 numbers, if I (randomly) choose `2,3` for first two numbers, then the configuration for the last two numbers could be either `0,1` or `1,0`. If I happen to choose say `1,2` for the first two, then the only available option left is `3,0` since the last bit can't be `3`. So it seems the probability of `1,2,3,0` is twice as high as `2,3,0,1`, right?

Another thing to do is to randomly generate a permutation and reject if it doesn't satisfy the condition, but the time complexity for this can't be guaranteed.

Comment: What you mean is "uniformly distributed". "randomly" does not say the probabilities are equal.

Comment: @Henry right, I meant "uniformly distributed" indeed

Comment: You could use a [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to randomize the initial sequence. In case, one element is wrongly placed, swap it with its neighbour. If more elements are wrongly placed, perform a second Fisher-Yates shuffle of these elements.

Comment: For large n the probability that a permutation has no fixed point tends to 1/e. So the strategy to reject permutations with a fixed point will on average need e (2.718...) tries. During the generation of the unrestricted permutation you can also "fail fast" if you detect that there will be a fixed point to speed the process up a bit. So this should not behave too badly in practice.

Comment: @Henry good to know that, thank you

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you that seems exactly my question

Answer (score 1):

You could do trial-and-error with [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). The probability of computing a permutation `P` with fixed points is `1-1/e` which means that the expected number of trials is `e` (or about three).

Here I am using the known fact that if the probability of seeing heads when throwing a biased coin is `p` then the expected number of trials until getting the first heads is `1/p`.

The total expected running time is then `O(n)`.

Also note that is asymptotically optimal as any algorithm that computes a random permutation without fixed points has to touch all of the elements.

Pseudo code:

```
generateRandomPermutation(n)
    do
        generate a random permutation P of {1,2,3,...,n} with Fisher-Yates // O(n)
    while there exists i with P[i] = i // Expected nr of iterations is e
    return P
```

Comment: @JohnColeman ah, I misunderstood the question. I thought that we are given an integer `i` which mustn't be fixed (and that this is the only constraint); in that case my argument works. If the problem is to find a permutation with no fixed points then yes, we expect to make three (actually `e`) iterations. Thanks for the heads-up; I updated the answer.

Comment: OP's question wasn't phrased very clearly since they neglected to quantify `i`. Your original interpretation was reasonable enough. As an optimization you can short-circuit Fisher-Yates as soon as you see a fixed point, though in languages that have a built-in shuffle it might not be worth the hassle.